# How do I program a mobile app to send SMS?

Tags: vb.net, mobile, windows-mobile, gsm

I want a mobile app to send automated SMS. This will be in VB.Net. I've searched for articles on these but they are all about PC apps accessing a GSM modem or a mobile through a COM port. Is it the same process with mobile apps on the phone (not through a PC)? If yes, and I am to treat the GSM modem as a "port", how would I connect to it? If no, are there any useful resources for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sending SMS is easy with windows mobile. You need a reference to mobile.poutlook namespace.

"*Send SMS from Pocket PC, SMartphones, Windows mobile*

*To send an SMS Message we’ll first need to make reference to the Microsoft.WindowsMobile.PocketOutlook namespace.*

```
Imports Microsoft.WindowsMobile.PocketOutlook
```

*After that it’s as simple as creating a new instance of the SMSMessage class with an overloaded onstructor passing in the Recipient Mobile number and SMS text, then invoking the Send method*"

[Source](http://www.sourcecodester.com/visual-basic-net/send-sms-windows-mobile-5-6xx-or-7.html).
[Download VB code directly](http://www.sourcecodester.com/sites/default/files/download/emond/smsmobile.zip).

[MS reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsmobile.pocketoutlook.smsmessage.send.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1).

MS Snippet:

```
public void SmsMessageSend()
{
    SmsMessage smsMessage = new SmsMessage();

    //Set the message body and recipient.
    smsMessage.Body = "Would you like to meet for lunch?";
    smsMessage.To.Add(new Recipient("John Doe", "2065550199"));
    smsMessage.RequestDeliveryReport = true;

    //Send the SMS message.
    smsMessage.Send();

    return;
}
```

An automated VB translation of the above snippet:

```
Public Sub SmsMessageSend()
    Dim smsMessage As New SmsMessage()

    'Set the message body and recipient.
    smsMessage.Body = "Would you like to meet for lunch?"

    smsMessage.To.Add(New Recipient("John Doe", "2065550199"))
    smsMessage.RequestDeliveryReport = True

    'Send the SMS message.
    smsMessage.Send()
    Return
End Sub
```

The above is not VB as asked, but unfortunately MS does not provide the VB snippet there.

All this will only work, if you are using a windows mobile device. It will not work on windows ce devices.

You should consider your internet searches for mobile API and code. I always start with "compact framework" to get code related results only. Then I add the keywords I search for. In example: "compact framework send sms" gives a good result list that you can work on.